# Setting up a direct wireless connection

Tags: networking, server, wireless, ssh, tunnel

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LS

I have a headless raspberry pi that I connect to my laptop and edit through an Ethernet cable. My goal is to get rid of the Ethernet cable. With no access to the internet, is it possible to connect to the raspberry pi (via ‘ssh’) without an Ethernet cable?

Right now I have a static IP address under device eth0 on the raspberry pi. I would like to be able to connect to it with no Ethernet cable, and no internet connection.

I believe it is possible, maybe through the use of tunneling?

Comment: Look up how to use "netplan" on the pi so it reliably connects to the correct wireless network, and uses the correct IP address settings.

Comment: You haven't provide OS/release details, nor mentioned if you have wifi enabled on your pi (I can access mine via `ssh` using ethernet or wifi); for if you're not using wifi either, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have access to WiFi yes, but no access to internet